# How to make d3js calendar and its contents responsive

Tags: d3.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am using this d3js calendar [code link](http://bit.ly/1Ft5Z23) and I need help in making this calendar at its contents responsive in a BS 3 div. Calling redraw after resizing the window does not resize the inner tiles or the calendar color blocks. So I tried to get the new dimensions and resize, but don't know what to do next...

```
//I can get the box, and get the aspect ratio
    var contr = d3.select(svg.node().parentnode)
    w = parseInt(svg.style("width "))
    h = parseInt(svg.style("height "))
    aspect = w / h;
```

Also in the [original code](http://bit.ly/1Ft5Z23) I want to make the cell and contents responsive. *When I looked at d3js, I couldn't get help on how they were tackling the cell*

```
//please help me understand how are they deriving the cell size, 
//and can I auto scale the cell size ??
var width = 960,
yearHeight = 136,
height = yearHeight * 20,
cellSize = 17; // cell size
```

Should I take additional precaution in using it with BS 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing responsive design with `d3`, I will generally pick one value (say `windown.innerWidth`) and adjust all values around it.  For instance, with the example you link, I'd use:

```
  var width = window.innerWidth - 30;
      yearHeight = width / 7,
      height = yearHeight * 20,
      cellSize = yearHeight / 8; // cell size
```

The `yearHeight / 8` just comes from experimentation and produces nice results.

The next step, then, is to catch the window resize and resize/reposition the calender elements:

```
function resize() {

  var width = window.innerWidth - 30;
      yearHeight = width / 7,
      height = yearHeight * 20,
      cellSize = yearHeight / 8; // cell size

  svg.attr("width", width)  // adjust svg
    .attr("height", height); 

  svg.selectAll(".RdYlGn")  // this is the g element around each year
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(" + ((width - cellSize * 53) / 2) + "," + ((yearHeight - cellSize * 7 - 1) + (yearHeight * i)) + ")";
    });

svg.selectAll(".month").attr("d", monthPath); // this is the path around each month

svg.selectAll(".day") // this is each day rect
  .attr("width", cellSize)
  .attr("height", cellSize)
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    d = format.parse(d); // re-parse the date
    return week(d) * cellSize;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    d = format.parse(d);
    return day(d) * cellSize;
  });
};
```

Here's a working [example](http://embed.plnkr.co/omtL2Ft6d154mw6MU17F/preview).

Comment: if only I could give you 200 thousand points, I would :))             thanks for the guidance on the cellsize... I wasn't sure how to get the ratio...  and you confirmed it was arbitrary!  Also, can I ask similar to how you parameterized the cell-size, is there a ratio I can use to fit the number of months in calendar in a div. For e.g in some cases, there are only 7 (spring + summer) months in a calendar, in others 4 (spring only, hiking permits or trout fishing). _Next I'm aiming to parametrize the entire calendar hopefully._

Comment: this work, but the browser hangs and locks up consitiently both in Chrome and Firefox.. any help